# Correct word for "The person who post a comment"

Tags: synonyms

In a situation of articles and comments, a comment is "posted by" someone. How to define the person who posted the comment?

Comment: That would be a “commenter”

Comment: Thanks! Please post this as an answer so I can accept it.

Comment: And, of course, the person who made the Original Post is OPie.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[**Commenter**](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/commenter):

> [Merriam-Webster]
>
> one who comments; *especially* : one who leaves a comment on an Internet site, story, page, etc.

---

Also note (all from Merriam-Webster):

**Questioner** (under [*question*](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/question)):

> *intransitive verb*
> to ask questions : [INQUIRE](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/inquire)
> — questioner *noun*

**Answerer** (under [*answer*](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/answer)):

> *intransitive verb*
> 1 : to speak or write in reply · neglected to answer the letter
> — answerer *noun*

Comment: The two additional words were quoted in a somewhat unintuitive way; I’ve changed the wording a bit to make it easier to parse. Feel free to undo if you don’t think it has the intended effect.

Comment: @JanusBahsJacquet  Thanks, that helped. I find every way of expressing this a bit awkward, but I take your point.